# Import not well formatted txt file using python (eliminate first rows)

Tags: python, pandas, import

I am trying to import a txt file to python and I'm using pandas.

The file I'm trying to import looks more or less like this:

```
Final Test Values
***************************
Date: Friday, 24 September
Version  :  Version 3.0(3)
ID L      : 1937
ID P     :  60
***************************
A ; B ; C ; D ; E ;  F 
-----------------------------------------------------------------
660    ;    25    ;      5.6478      ;    0.9381     ;   0.67  ;    8.00
661    ;    25    ;      6.2592      ;    0.6103     ;   0.52  ;    8.00
662    ;    25    ;      6.7193      ;    0.5644     ;   0.52  ;    8.00
663    ;    25    ;      4.3940      ;    1.0760     ;   0.54  ;    8.00
664    ;    25    ;      6.4188      ;    0.5507     ;   0.54  ;    8.00
665    ;    25    ;      6.5221      ;    0.5619     ;   0.00  ;    8.00
```

The values that I am really interested in is just this part:

```
660    ;    25    ;      5.6478      ;    0.9381     ;   0.67  ;    8.00
661    ;    25    ;      6.2592      ;    0.6103     ;   0.52  ;    8.00
662    ;    25    ;      6.7193      ;    0.5644     ;   0.52  ;    8.00
663    ;    25    ;      4.3940      ;    1.0760     ;   0.54  ;    8.00
664    ;    25    ;      6.4188      ;    0.5507     ;   0.54  ;    8.00
665    ;    25    ;      6.5221      ;    0.5619     ;   0.00  ;    8.00
```

The date, ID L and ID P can vary everytime.

I have done the entire code by manually opening the txt file and deleting everything until the 660, but that is obviously not the best way to do it.

[What I have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOcew.png)

Anyone has any suggestion?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `skiprows` argument to ignore the rows you don't need:

```
data = StringIO("""Final Test Values
***************************
Date: Friday, 24 September
Version  :  Version 3.0(3)
ID L      : 1937
ID P     :  60
***************************
A ; B ; C ; D ; E ;  F 
-----------------------------------------------------------------
660    ;    25    ;      5.6478      ;    0.9381     ;   0.67  ;    8.00
661    ;    25    ;      6.2592      ;    0.6103     ;   0.52  ;    8.00
662    ;    25    ;      6.7193      ;    0.5644     ;   0.52  ;    8.00
663    ;    25    ;      4.3940      ;    1.0760     ;   0.54  ;    8.00
664    ;    25    ;      6.4188      ;    0.5507     ;   0.54  ;    8.00
665    ;    25    ;      6.5221      ;    0.5619     ;   0.00  ;    8.00
""")
```

```
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=";", skiprows=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,8])

    A    B       C       D     E     F 
0  660   25  5.6478  0.9381  0.67   8.0
1  661   25  6.2592  0.6103  0.52   8.0
2  662   25  6.7193  0.5644  0.52   8.0
3  663   25  4.3940  1.0760  0.54   8.0
4  664   25  6.4188  0.5507  0.54   8.0
5  665   25  6.5221  0.5619  0.00   8.0
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked!